# How do I mock UserManager.GetRoles()

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mocking, asp.net-identity

How do I mock UserManager.GetRoles() in ASP.NET Identity? I know it's an extension method, so I can't mock it directly and I can't find the underlying methods/properties that need to be mocked.

In the past, I was able to mock the extension method UserManager.FindByName() by mocking the UserStore,

```
var mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
mockUserStore.Setup(x => x.FindByNameAsync(username))
                     .ReturnsAsync(new ApplicationUser() { OrganizationId = orgId });
var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(mockUserStore.Object);
```

I don't see any way to assign Roles to the Users in the UserStore. Any ideas?

I also tried this, but won't compile because UserManager.GetRoles() is an extension method. I get this error: "'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager' does not contain a definition for 'GetRoles'"

```
public interface IApplicationUserManager
{
    IList<string> GetRoles<TUser, TKey>(TKey userId)
        where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>;
}

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationUserManager
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
    public IList<string> GetRoles<TUser, TKey>(TKey userId)
        where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        return base.GetRoles(userId);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Valentin, I *think* I tried your suggestion and am getting a compiler error because GetRoles() is an extension method on the UserManager class. I edited the question with what I tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can make wrapper for  `UserManager`

```
interface IUserManagerWrapper 
{
     roles GetRoles ();
}

public class MyUserManager : IUserManagerWrapper 
{
      GetRoles () 
    {
         return UserManager.GetRoles()
    }
}
```

And use `IUserManagerWrapper` instead of `UserManager.GetRoles()`, hence you can mock it.

Comment: @drewob You'll find this pattern of using interfaces instead of concrete classes makes it much easier to mock things (and swap out different implementations)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up extracting an interface for ApplicationUserManager containing GetRoles. Then I added GetRoles() to ApplicationUserManager, which calls the extension method class.

```
public interface IApplicationUserManager
{
    IList<string> GetRoles(string userId);
}

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationUserManager
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public IList<string> GetRoles(string userId)
    {
        return UserManagerExtensions.GetRoles(manager: this, userId: userId);
    }
}
```

Now I can mock IApplicationUserManager.GetRoles().